# Sparksql saveAsTable call the wrong hdfs port

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I configured a hadoop cluster with hadoop 2.6.3, spark 2.0.0(previously 1.6.1),hive 2.0;

Recently, I changed the hadoop port specification.
One major change is for the ***fs.defaultFS*** in core-site.xml.
I changed this property from

```
hdfs://10.104.90.40:9000
```

to

```
hdfs://10.104.90.40:8020
```

After that I restated hadoop.
Now I want to write a table to hive with SparkSql with code:

```
 df=sqlContext.sql('select * from vehicle')
 df.take(1)              //this can show the content correctly
 df.write.saveAsTable('try')
```

However, it always fail with the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o405.saveAsTable.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From namenode01-bi-dev/10.104.90.40 to 
namenode01-bi-dev:9000 failed on connection exception:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Back before when I was with spark 1.6.1(already changed the  fs.defaultFS port to 8020), this exact same would pop up when  I run the saveAsTable command.
It's obvious that the error result from trying connect to a port which is no longer used.

I tryied the following command to find whether I forgot change some setting , only to find out no configuration file contain content of "9000"

```
grep -rnw '/usr/local/' -e "9000"
```

Everything else works fine, the folloing command or code can all work fine

```
hadoop fs -put/get 
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS //the outout is hdfs://10.104.90.40:8020
//within pyspark-shell
ff=sc.textFile("somefile")
ff.saveAsTextFile("/ll")
```

It doesn't make any sense to me that saveAsTable would call the 9000 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting hive metastore,

```
sudo service hive-metastore restart
```

Comment: The same error remian After restarting the hive metastore

Comment: Okay.
Check the FS location in hive by typing
`$HIVE_HOME/bin` 
`metatool -listFSRoot`
If it shows old path update it

Comment: This actually solve the problem. The listFSRoot does give back old hdfs port. After updating the location. The error is gone and I can successfully write to hive. Thanks !

Comment: You may accept this Answer, upvote. Can be helpful to others